# Как закрасить область в chart C#, ограниченную серией Line

Tags: c#, winforms, диаграммы

У меня есть набор точек, по которому я строю замкнутую область. Использую C# Chart SeriesType:Line. Она выглядит следующим образом:

[image: Chart Line]

Мне же нужно закрасить данную область. Стандартного типа Series не нашел (ближе всего Area, но она закрашивает область полностью до 0 по y).

Спасибо заранее за ответы и предложения.

Comment: Если вы не нашли подходящий тип диаграммы среди стандартных, значит стандартный контрол Chart этого не умеет. Он вообще мало умеет.

Comment: Не уверен, что правильно понял, что вы хотите получить

Comment: @FoggyFinder получить нужно кастомный график с закрашенной замкнутой областью. Стандартный Chart это не умеет. Код контрола закрыт, во всяком случае его нет на refferncesource, поэтому даже подглядеть от что нужно унаследовать и переопределить не выйдет, в доках этого нет. Так что тут глухо, проще самому нарисовать график на Panel. Искать в сторонних библиотеках можно, но скорее всего бесполезно, слишком нестандартное решение нужно, а в готовых контролах только более-менее стандартные вещи есть и то не все

Answer (score 1):

С компонентом `Chart` как и вообще с `WindowsForms` работал крайне мало, но поиски информации по вашему вопросу привели к одному из способов решения.

Занести все точки, которые определяют вашу фигуру в [GraphicsPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath(v=vs.110).aspx), а затем отобразить их с помощью [Graphics.FillPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fillpath(v=vs.110).aspx)

Пример:

```
        Series some = new Series("Some");

        some.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

        some.Color = Color.Red;
        some.BorderWidth = 3;

        //коллекция точек
        some.Points.AddXY(10, 10);
        some.Points.AddXY(40, 10);
        some.Points.AddXY(40, 60);
        some.Points.AddXY(40, 70);
        some.Points.AddXY(10, 60);
        some.Points.AddXY(10, 10);

        chart.Series.Add(some);
```

...

```
    private void Chart_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var graphics = e.Graphics;

        GraphicsPath gp = new GraphicsPath(FillMode.Winding);

        Axis ax = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
        Axis ay = chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;

        PointF[] points =
             chart
             .Series["Some"]
             .Points
             .Select(x =>
                    new PointF
                    {
                        X = (float)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(x.XValue),
                        Y = (float)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(x.YValues[0])
                    })
             .ToArray();

        gp.AddLines(points);

        using (SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green))
            graphics.FillPath(brush, gp);

        gp.Dispose();
    }
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]